# Magento2 - Save Quote (Repository / Cart) Default Shipping Values

Tags: magento2, quote

I am adding a shipping address with a same_as_billing value of 0, after adding this address to the cart / via the repository the value in the database for same_as_billing is 1 on the shipping address row.

I am trying to add the addresses in separate actions, is there (and if so where is it) any kind of mechanism that by default adds a shipping address with a same_as_billing value of 1 if it isn't set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found it:** Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address

```
protected function _populateBeforeSaveData()
{
    if ($this->getQuote()) {
        $this->_dataSaveAllowed = (bool)$this->getQuote()->getId();

        if ($this->getQuote()->getId()) {
            $this->setQuoteId($this->getQuote()->getId());
        }
        $this->setCustomerId($this->getQuote()->getCustomerId());

        /**
         * Init customer address id if customer address is assigned
         */
        if ($this->getCustomerAddressData()) {
            $this->setCustomerAddressId($this->getCustomerAddressData()->getId());
        }

        if (!$this->getId()) {
            $this->setSameAsBilling((int)$this->_isSameAsBilling());
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Returns true if shipping address is same as billing
 *
 * @return bool
 */
protected function _isSameAsBilling()
{
    return $this->getAddressType() == \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address::TYPE_SHIPPING &&
        ($this->_isNotRegisteredCustomer() ||
        $this->_isDefaultShippingNullOrSameAsBillingAddress());
}
```